# navigate up the folder structure

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, requirejs

Under my `wwwrooot` folder I have a sub folder named **scripts** which has the following structure:

- scripts (folder)

  - `options.js`

    - components (folder)

      - `require.js`
      - `jquery.js` and many more in this folder

I have the following script on my ASP.NET webpage (under `_Layout.cshtml`):

```
<script src="~/scripts/components/require.js" data-main="scripts/options"></script>
```

This is supposed to go to my `wwwroot` folder to scripts/components and start `require.js`, where as a parameter I am passing `script/options.js` file.

(quick note: this was given to me, I did not create it).

Unfortunately, it returns the error that it could not localize my options.js file. By looking into the console window, the GET function should be expecting the following path:

`http://localhost:8000/scripts/options.js`

whereas on my page GET function is trying to access the following file:

`http://localhost:8000/app/scripts/options.js`

I believe it is caused by the fact, that my MVC start page is under App controller (to be more precise it is App/index.html).

I believe (correct me if I am wrong), that the problem can be fixed by somehow removing the /app/ from the search string. Unfortunately, I don't quite know how to do it.

Any help on this matter would be more than welcome.

Comment: did you try `data-main="/scripts/options"`?

Comment: `<script src="../scripts/components/require.js" data-main="scripts/options"></script>` note the two dots

Comment: I tried both of your solutions, but then it gave me the following error `http://localhost:8000/app/scripts/components/jquery.js `. It seems like it for unknown reason cannot remove the **/app/** from there